# Which of my two SSD drives is drive C

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I have just received a new PC with two SSD drives, one is an ordinary Samsung SSD and the other is an M.2 Seagate Firecuda. I thought I'd just check that the builder correctly put the OS on the faster Firecuda drive so I right-clicked on my drive C Icon then selected properties then clicked the hardware tab. To my surprise I saw both drives listed, so I am none the wiser.

**EDIT:** Picture added as requested.

[image]

**EDIT:** and another...
[image]

Comment: Look at Disk Mangement

Comment: @Ramhound: Looking now but still can't see the answer. BTW, both drives have the same capacity, so no clues there.

Comment: Could be that there are setup in some kind of RAID setup? I mean, SSDs like that would be useful for something like that.

Comment: I guess it's possible (and not what I requested) - how could I tell for sure?

Comment: Provide a screenshot in that case

Comment: A screenshot of Disk Management not the properties of a your C drive.

Comment: What does explorer show as drive letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Disk Management right-click on the Disk 0 or Disk 1, and select properties.

This will show you the properties for that specific drive, including the Serial Number, which will allow you to figure out which drive your C drive is on.

Comment: I just see both drives listed again.

Comment: Hmmmm, it'll be a bit before I get to my own multi-drive computer to check. I'll get back to you.

Comment: If you see both drives listed you're doing it wrong. Specifically, right click on the label that says "Disk 0 Basic..." on the lower right area of the Disk Management window, and select properties. Don't right click on the partition. When you right click ON Disk 0 or Disk 1 and select properties you'll get the properties (and identifiers) for that specific drive. I have just now confirmed this is the case on a Windows 10 2004 system with multiple hard drives installed.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. Well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

You can are 2 clicks from the answer.  In the bottom half of the screen, right click the gray area where it says "Disk 0 Basic 1862.89 GB Online" and select "Properties" and it will tell you which disk that is.

Most disk controllers I have seen (maybe all) put M.2 drives after traditional SATA ports.

On a side note, I wouldnt install the OS on the fastest drive.  SSDs are plenty fast and I dont care how fast my computer boots up or shuts down, as I never turn it off.  However, I do want my applications to run as fast as possible, which would mean putting them on the fastest drive.

Comment: I just see both drives listed again.

Comment: @Mick In Disk Management?

Answer (score 0):

Go to search bar at the bottom. Type `This Pc` and select it. Right click on any of the hard drives you see and select properties. Go to the hardware tab like you did in your first picture. Double click on any of the drives you see there and select the volumes tab. When there click populate and it will tell you the letter associated with that drive. Hope this helped.